# maven nexus download central remote indexes error

Tags: maven, maven-2, nexus

Nexus version 2.12.0-01 and jdk 1.7

when I set central repository Download Remote Indexes to true. I got this error

```
jvm 1 | 2016-05-17 14:05:57,862+0800 INFO [ar-7-thread-2] admin 
org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.maven.routing.internal.RemoteContentDiscovererImpl 
- Remote strategy prefix-file on M2Repository(id=central) detected invalid 
input, results discarded: Prefix file size exceeds maximum allowed size 
(100000), refusing to load it.
```

I did not find any info on google ):

thanks in advance

Comment: For central repository, prefix file is having an invalid size, check your prefix file

Comment: @a3.14_Infinity thanks :) could you tell me where is the prefix file

Comment: Hi, Could you please refer to https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-managing-routes.html

Answer (score 6):

This is a bug: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-10233

This bug won't cause any malfunction of your central proxy, but it does cause automatic routing to be disabled. Automatic routing is just an optimization.  See here for further explanation:

https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465588-How-does-Automatic-Routing-work-

We are working on a fix for this now.  In the meantime, there is a workaround, see [here](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-10233?focusedCommentId=357992&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-357992)